# Small step vs big step semantics for static analysis?

Tags: semantics, operational-semantics, static-analysis, small-step-semantics

To be an honest question poster I do not yet fully grasp the difference between small step and big step semantics. There was a good discussion [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43294/difference-between-small-and-big-step-operational-semantics)

My question is if I were to do static analysis on a file to determine if it is malware, what would be better to use: small step or big step semantics?

To take this a step further if I am doing dynamic analysis which would be best: small step or big step semantics?

Preferably a simple example as to why would be much appreciated.